# Manwha that opens with a protagonist evading a boss to mine some rocks and gets a really rare drop (possibly armor)

Tags: story-identification, manga

So this manwha starts with a guy who is in a game type world and he runs past this boss fight to mine some rocks and I think gets a really rare drop or something. I think the drop he gets was armor.

I vaguely remember reading the beginning, but I am pretty sure that's what happened.

Comment: idk if identification requests are still allowed here, but in general if you're looking for something popular, just google "isekai manhwa" and you'll probably find it among the "top 10 best" lists within an hour. This works for most works, not just mangas, manhwas or anime.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 2):

The title of the manhwa is [*Overgeared*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/overgeared).

> As Shin Youngwoo has had an unfortunate life and is now stuck carrying bricks on construction sites. He even had to do labor in the VR game, Satisfy! However, luck would soon enter his hopeless life. His character, ‘Grid’, would discover the Northern End Cave for a quest, and in that place, he would find ‘Pagma’s Rare Book’ and become a legendary class player…